# Multiple Monitors (and a TV)

Tags: multiple-monitors

I am considering changing from Windows 10 to a Linux Based OS.   My Big question is that in Windows, I have stretched my desktop over two monitors and mirrored the second monitor to my HDMI TV...  I am using a liquid cooled AMD card (for all three devices).  The TV is on my HDMI port, my monitors are using the VGA and DisplayPort.
All three support 1920x1080 resolution... or something like that...the websites i have seen talked about configuring monitors from multiple cards as all three being stretched or all three being mirrored..... Is there a way to do a combination (using just 1 card) ?   I also wonder If there is a driver for my display card in Linux...   if needed, please tell me how to locate the model and other info if needed to answer if the driver is available.

Comment: I found my video card info Adapter Description AMD Radeon (TM) R9 380 Series
 and on board RAM is Adapter RAM (1,048,576) bytes
and the two monitors support 60 hertz... i am unsure if the tv supports 60 hz, but my guess is that it does....

Comment: Not sure if this is even relevant, but after further inspection of my computer, there seems to be an on-board video card which has a port for HDMI, VGA, and some white port with a - sign at the end.  ( the liquid cooled video card isn't running a VGA port)...   the TV is definitely on the HDMI slot,  The monitors are using two Black Ports (one has several pins, and the other is more of a rectangle with several connections inside the cable (but not pins)...  i don't know which one is the Display Port, but one monitor is on a Display Port.   It acts like the on-board video card is disabled.

Comment: Welcome to [ubuntu.se]! You should [edit] your question to reflect all the details you posted in the comments. It helps to keep our Q&A style tidy and could also bring more attention since an edited question gets bounced on the homepage. See also [How do comments work?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/19756/217657)

Answer (score 2):

I used the command `xrandr` to give me a list of my monitor names (DVI-D-0, DisplayPort-0, HDMI-A-0) and I used the following command to achieve what I wanted (which was to have my primary as a main) and monitor 2 and the TV mirrored.  since there are several types of linux versions available, you may have to use a different command.

```
xrandr --output DVI-D-0 --output DisplayPort-0 --output HDMI-A-0 --same-as DisplayPort-0
```